# Странное поведение массива при работе find()

Tags: c++

Здравья желаю

Пишу программу для перебора текстового файла и нахождения в нём нужного символа(слова)  и тут...

наткнулся на аномалию:))
вот блок кода:

```
std::fstream input(dir, std::ios::in|std::ios::out|std::ios::app);
   if(!input){std::cout<<"FILE_ERROR"<<std::endl; return;}
   std::string buffer;
   int arr_find[20], i=0;

   do{
      std::getline(input, buffer);//чтение строки
      arr_find[i] = buffer.find(account);//возвращает 0 если найден нужный символ
      if(arr_find[i] == 0){
         break;
      }else{i++;}
      std::cout<<arr_find[i]<<":"<<i<<std::endl;//вывод массива
   }while(!input.eof());
```

создаётся массив типа int (arr_find[20]) для заполнения работы функции find()
 из библиотеки string.h(cstring.h).

Массив должен заполнятся значениями -1 или 0(0 если найден нужный символ(строка)).

Прогоняю программу через файл.txt, ищу "asd":

```
a
s
z
xc
af
f
sss
asd
```

И на выходе получаю вывод массива:

```
3:1
1989621908:2
6356060:3
1989316383:4
6356088:5
1877822365:6
6356680:7
```

работаю в vim, командная строка Windows, MinGW32

Я уже не знаю что и думать, причин такому поведению я не вижу. Прошу помочь указать на мои ошибки.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что если `arr_find[i]` не равен 0. То есть строка не нашлась на нулевом месте, то вы прибавляете к `i` единицу:

```
if(arr_find[i] == 0){
         break;
      }else{i++;}
```

После чего вы выводите значение ячейки `arr_find[i]`, но это не та ячейка, в которую вы записали результат, а следующая. А в этой ячейки может находиться всё, что угодно. Так как она была заполнена случайным числом при создании и больше не изменялась.

---

Можно переписать следующий код так:

```
if(arr_find[i] == 0) {
         break;
} 
else {
    std::cout << arr_find[i] << ':' << i << std::endl;  // вывод массива
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе человек, @retorta)), что бы я без тебя делал...